# SMTP Mail delivery failed for URIBL query refused

Tags: smtp, blacklist, spam-filter

I'm experiencing some trouble with a single recipient because his mail server refuse my email.

This is the error reply:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<xxxx@xxx.xxx>:
554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [51.255.xxx.xxx] blocked using multi.uribl.com; 127.0.0.1 -> Query Refused. See http://uribl.com/refused.shtml for more information [Your DNS IP:89.119.xxx.xxx]
```

I read the linked page http://uribl.com/refused.shtml but my server ip is not listed in this list, what should I do?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to send email to [this guy](http://serverfault.com/q/774302/126632)? It's a problem on the recipient's end; there is nothing you can do but try to notify him by some other method (e.g. phone).

Comment: Ok I will try to contact his postmaster. Thank you.